# python multiprocessing (ThreadPool) taking longer to execute than sequential

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am new to the `multiprocessing` module in python. I have a test code below which calculates the time it takes to execute a function both in sequential form and in a pool of threads:\

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import timeit


def foo(n):

    for i in range(700000):
        n += 1
    return n


inputs = [1,2, 3, 4]

start = timeit.default_timer()

pool = ThreadPool(4)

results = pool.map(foo, inputs)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(timeit.default_timer() - start)
print(results)

start = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range(4):
    foo(i+1)

print(timeit.default_timer() - start)
```

This is the result I keep getting:

```
0.3945475000073202
[700001, 700002, 700003, 700004]
0.2912912300089374

Process finished with exit code 0
```

How is it that the sequential algorithm is faster then the threaded one? I know overhead is expected when you create threads however I made `foo` such that it takes a good amount of time to compute. should multithreading with 4 threads take (roughly) a quarter of the time the sequential algorithm takes? 
To me this is really strange because when I test the below algorithm which is basically the same with a difference in the `foo` function I get much better results in terms of speed up:

```
def foo(n):  
   time.sleep(n)


inputs = [1, 1, 1, 1]
start = timeit.default_timer()

pool = ThreadPool(4)

results = pool.map(foo, inputs)

pool.close()
pool.join()

print("Threaded - " + str(timeit.default_timer() - start))

start = timeit.default_timer()

for i in range(4):
    foo(1)

print("sequential - " + str(timeit.default_timer() - start))
```

with this code the multithreading seems to be working fine:

```
Threaded - 1.2794823400327004
sequential - 4.011253927950747

Process finished with exit code 0
```